# Extjs composing component

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I 'm using ExtJs4.1, and I need to create a new textField, with a custom button at right side.

my first attempt was to create a container with a textField and a button inside:

```
{
   xtype: 'container',
   layout: 'hbox',
   items:[
     {xtype:'textField', flex:1},
     {xtype:'button', width:17}  
   ]
}
```

In fact, I will use this component in many places, so I need to create a custom control.

How can I do this, remembering that the textField is the most important control.

Comment: What do you mean by "custom control" ? Do you want to define this container as separate component ie. `Ext.container.Container` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define it. You can give it an xtype alias to refer to it easily. Make sure that it is loaded before you try to call it (by using 'requires').

```
Ext.define('My.namespace.Component', {
  extend: 'Ext.container.Container',  //extend Container
  alias: 'widget.mycomponent',        //this is the xtype (minus 'widget.')

  layout:{
    type:'hbox'
  },

  initComponent:function(){

    Ext.applyIf(this, {
          items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Label',
                    flex: 1
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'MyButton',
                    flex: 1
                }
            ]
    });

    this.callParent(arguments); //everything breaks if you forget this
  }
});
```

in a view or other component, use requires to load the above component:

```
...
requires:[
  'My.namespace.Component'
]
...
```

Use it like this:

```
{
  xtype:'mycomponent',
  width:666
}
```

Comment: But in this case, my base class is "container". There is a way to be "textField" ?

Comment: why does it have to be a textfield and not a container?

Comment: It would be even better to write this as a plugin.

Comment: if I want to use like this: {
  xtype:'mycomponent',
  fieldLabel:"First Name"
}

Answer (score 0):

Making a resource, I found the "Trigger field" solution:

```
Ext.define('App.controls.CoTextField',{
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.Trigger',
    alias: 'widget.cotextfield',
    triggerCls: 'x-form-trigger',
    trigger2Cls: 'x-form-clear-trigger',
    onTriggerClick: function() {
        alert('Down button');
    },
    onTrigger2Click: function() {
        alert('Clear button');
    }

});
```